# Command Window Output with MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am pretty new to MATLAB GUI. I've attempted to teach it to myself the last few weeks so I can understand and improve some code that is being developed where I work. GUI is still a fairly new concept to me.

I am wondering: I need the command window to output the mean of a set of data according to a function that is called by pressing a button on the GUI. Where would I include this code and how should I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: See: [callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html) and [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)/[`disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the code by using 'disp' or 'fprintf' functions. Notice that converts your content to compatible with the function.